# How to prove, that $(p, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ is a prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ for prime $p\in\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

I am wondering if $I:=(p,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is a prime ideal of $R:=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. I just tried to use the definition of the index and used to show that this is $2$. Since $R$ is a Dedekind domain, this shows the primality.

I can't find any argument for proving $[R:I]=2$. Could someone help me out, please?

Thanks

Comment: You may try to show that $R/I$ is an integral domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not entirely true. For most primes $p$, the ideal $I$ is the unit ideal. If $(1)$ is a prime ideal depends on your taste I guess.

Anyways, here's one way to compute in this case: note that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] = \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+5)$. Here $x$ correspond to $\sqrt{-5}$. Dividing out by the ideal $I$ is the same computing
$$
\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+5,p,1+x).
$$

Here I use that dividing out by $I$ first then by $J$ is the same as dividing out by $I+J$. Explicitly, any ideal $J \subset R/I$ lifts to an ideal $\overline J$ containing $I$. So we can write $\overline J = I+ J'$ (just let overline $J'$ be generated by the elements of $\overline J$ not in $I$). Then $R/(I+J') \simeq (R/I)/J$.

But dividing out by $1+x$ is the same as putting $x=-1$ in the quotient ring. Do you see the rest?

Comment: Well if i consider (1) not as a prime ideal, are there any primes for disprove it? 

I guess I am not able to prove that at all. Why did you chose "1+x"? Could you give a small guide for that prove? Thank you :)

I guess I see, why its 1+x. You are going to identify x with $\sqrt{-5}$, so it turns $1+\sqrt{-5}=1+x$, right?
But why is there only one ideal and not the product $(x^2+5)(p,1+x)$?

Comment: @Shalec I've clarified my answer somewhat. Does it help?

Comment: Ah...yes I remember on that part: $R/(I+J')= (R/i)/J$. Maybe it's lil' to late for me today (10+ pm here), but I guess all important things are written down. One fact seems to be most important: $x=-1$. 
Every coefficient should be reduced by p. Then you're putting $x=-1$. 

Maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction: I try to use this information for showing that there are no zero divisors in that quotient. Am I on the right trace?

Comment: Isn't it isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: nvm. It isn't isomorphic. It's neither $(11,1+\sqrt{-5})$ prime, because $(11)$ is, so $(11)$ is maximal. Since $(11)\neq (11,1+\sqrt{-5})$ it follows $(11,1+\sqrt{-5})=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and therefor not prime.

Comment: I think except $2,3$ for every other $p$ it will be the whole ring.